# PostgreSQL 9.3: Setting parameters values default to null

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following funtion which contains 6 parameters.

Here I want to set the default value null to the parameters `cola`,`colc` and `colf`.

**Function**: `fun_Test`

```
create or replace function fun_Test
(
    cola int default null,
    colb varchar(10),
    colc int default null,
    cold varchar(10),
    cole varchar(10),
    colf varchar(50) default null
)

returns void AS

$$
begin
    raise info '%',cola;
    raise info '%',colb;
    raise info '%',colc;
    raise info '%',cold;
    raise info '%',cole;
    raise info '%',colf;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

But getting an error.

**ERROR**:  input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, According to the error I need to set some values to other parameters. How to set `default not null` to other parameters?

Comment: You need to define default values for every parameter after the first one with a default value (in your case `cold` and `cole`). There is no "not null" constraint for parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reorder your parameters! Just place the ones with defaults at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION 
fun_Test (
     colb VARCHAR(10)
    ,cold VARCHAR(10)
    ,cole VARCHAR(10)
    ,colf VARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,colc INT = NULL
    ,cola INT = NULL
    )
```

As per [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)

**default_expr**

> An expression to be used as default value if the parameter is not
>   specified. The expression has to be coercible to the argument type of
>   the parameter. Only input (including INOUT) parameters can have a
>   default value. All input parameters following a parameter with a
>   default value must have default values as well.